# Need email open and click events from Amazon (aws) ses

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am sending the emails using Amazon AWS and want to track the email open and click count/notifications like bounce. Is it possible to do with aws ses?

Answer (score 6):

Update: Amazon SES added support for this earlier this week.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/ses/open-and-click-tracking-have-arrived/

Comment: Link only answers are not useful because links break. You should include key text from the link so that the answer is still helpful, even if the link goes down.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT:

As of August 2017, AWS started supporting Open and Click tracking:

See: [Open and Click Tracking Have Arrived](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/open-and-click-tracking-have-arrived/)

> When you send an email using Amazon SES, we now collect metrics
>   related to opens and clicks. **Opens**, in this sense, refers to the
>   number of users who successfully received your email and opened it in
>   their email clients; **clicks** refers to the number of users who received
>   an email and clicked one or more links in it.

Comment: sendgrid allows 3,000 per month for free, while SES gives 60,000 free per month. i hope they add click tracking and open tracking, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this with Amazon SES. There are a couple of ways to do this. One that is very flexible is "event publishing". It is simply telling Amazon to send events for your emails to a destination – a webhook for example

1. Go to your SES dashboard and create a configuration set
2. In destination, select SNS. Check the events you want to track and
   create a topic.
3. Add an http/http subscription to the topic once created. Set the
   subscription destination your webhook. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/event-publishing-retrieving-sns-contents.html) is what the content sent to the webhook will look like.
4. Anytime you want to send a mail to be tracked, specify the configuration set name in your SMTP mail header like this `X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET: config-set-name`.

That's it. For a more detailed explanation, see https://engage.so/blog/tracking-deliveries-opens-clicks-failures-and-complaints-for-amazon-ses/